# How to Setup TP-Link WR841N for external captive portal

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, openwrt

How to configure external captive portal using external radius server.
I can find the option to add radius server but not able to locate the option to add the redirect Login URL(URL which is redirected automatically when connected to my Wifi Hotspot).

Do I need to flash it with open-wrt or dd-wrt?

Answer (score 0):

unless your router is support to captive portal you have to flash it , before flash it make sure your router is supported by Open-wrt or Dd-wrt by going to their web site

Comment: Post 2016 new tp-link routers now don't support flashing the router.